# Put message on Facebook/Messenger programmatically

Tags: facebook

I want to put a link programmatically on Facebook/Messenger.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "<div class='addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style' 
        addthis:url='https://www.ietsdoen.nu/uitnodiging/' addthis:title='een titel' addthis:description='een beschrijving'> 
<a class='addthis_button_messenger'></a></div>";
?>
```

When a user clicks the button a form appears with 2  inputs: To and Message. When he/she leaves the To-input empty, the link appears on Facebook in the message. But when he/she types something into the To-input, the link does't appear. Only the typed text appears. Is it possible to put both the text and the link in the message on Facebook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: why not just use the share dialog?